# JAVA- Date Interval time, wrong results

Tags: java, date, time

Helo,
I have a problem with the subtraction of two dates because the result is not correct:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException, InterruptedException{

  DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss"); 
  long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
  Thread.sleep(3000);
  long goal = System.currentTimeMillis();

  long wyn = goal - start;
  Date result = new Date(wyn);
  System.out.println("Test1: " + format.format(result));
}
```

RESULT:
Test1: 01:00:03

There should be only three seconds between start and stop - why is there one hour? (depend on summer/winter time?) 
I need count time between start and end my program and I just want to get hours, minutes and seconds. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are converting the interval into a `Date` object. **This is wrong.**

The `Date` object is used to represent a point in time, **not** an interval of time.

What you should do is the following:

```
long wyn = goal - start;
System.out.println("Test1: " + wyn); //prints the interval in milliseconds
```

Result:

```
Test1: 3000
```

If you construct a `Date` object using `wyn`, you're creating a `Date` object that represents the point in time 3 seconds after *"the epoch"* (January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT).

The reason you see the hour is because time zones used in the year 1970 are different from those used now. For the same reason, I get `Test1: 07:30:03`.

Answer (score 4):

The `Date` class is not meant for intervals. It is meant for specific moment in time. The following

```
long wyn = goal - start;
```

will be equal to around `3000`. That's 3000 milliseconds after [Unix Epoch](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) when used as an argument for the `Date` constructor. Depending on your timezone, that will be some number of hours + 3 seconds.

---

Consider using the [Joda Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) API which has an `Interval` interface you can use for calculating intervals.

Comment: One note for the sake of correctness: it's [**Unix epoch**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time#History), not Linux epoch.

Answer (score 0):

To get the format you want, without misusing the Date class:

```
  public static String toHMS(int milliseconds){
    DecimalFormat twoDigit = new DecimalFormat("00");
    int secs = milliseconds/1000;
    String secsString = twoDigit.format(secs%60);
    int minutes = secs/60;
    String minsString = twoDigit.format(minutes%60);
    int hours = minutes/60;
    String hoursString = twoDigit.format(hours);
    return hoursString + ":" + minsString + ":" + secsString;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by ADTC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20923507/642706) is correct.

Rolling your own date-time calculations is risky business. Time zones, [Daylight Savings Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) (DST), and [other anomalies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6841479/642706) make such attempts failure-prone.

And rolling your own is silly since we have well-written and debugged code at our disposal. Currently we have the Joda-Time library, and with Java 8 we'll have the new java.time.* classes (inspired by Joda-Time). Joda-Time has classes built just for the purpose you are trying to jerry-rig, handling a span of time.

The following is copied from an answer I posted recently to a similar question, showing how to properly define a span of time and render a string describing that span.

---

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.3 library makes this kind of work easier. Look at the [Period](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Period.html), [Duration](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Duration.html), and [Interval](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) classes.

In contrast to a java.util.Date, in Joda-Time a `DateTime` instance does indeed know its assigned time zone.

The [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard defines a way to describe [durations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) as hours, minutes, and such in a `PnYnMnDTnHnMnS` format. I use that in my example code below. Joda-Time offers other ways as well.

```java
// © 2013 Basil Bourque. This source code may be used freely forever by anyone taking full responsibility for doing so.
// import org.joda.time.*;
// import org.joda.time.format.*;

DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "Europe/London" );
DateTime dateTimeNew = new DateTime( timeZone );
DateTime dateTimeOld = dateTimeNew.minusHours( 2 );

Period period = new Period( dateTimeOld, dateTimeNew );
```

Dump to console…

```java
System.out.println( "dateTimeNew: " + dateTimeNew );
System.out.println( "dateTimeOld: " + dateTimeOld );
System.out.println( "period: " + period );
```

When run…

```
dateTimeNew: 2014-01-02T23:19:45.021Z
dateTimeOld: 2014-01-02T21:19:45.021Z
period: PT2H
```